# Select random option from select list

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

How to select random option from select list using page-object?
I use:

```
  def select_random_member
    lstMembers = self.sltMembers_element.options.map(&:index) # getting all members from select list
    lastMember = lstMembers.last
    rnmMember = rand(0..lastMember)
    self.sltMembers_element.options[rnmMember].click
  end
```

I see a DEPRECATION WARNING for getting each option `lstMembers = self.sltEndDate_element.options.map(&:index)`

```
*** DEPRECATION WARNING
*** You are calling a method named index at D:/members/lib/pages/members_page.rb:58:in `map'.
*** This method does not exist in page-object so it is being passed to the driver.
*** This feature will be removed in the near future.
*** Please change your code to call the correct page-object method.
*** If you are using functionality that does not exist in page-object please request it be added.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `options` method returns an array of option elements. Arrays have a built-in method called [`sample`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sample) for selecting a random item.

Using `sample` the method would be:

```
def select_random_member
  sltMembers_element.options.sample.click
end
```

Comment: that seems like the way to go, OP.  +1

Answer (score 1):

try using [#sample](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sample) on `lstMembers`:

```
def select_random_member
  lstMembers = self.sltMembers_element.options.map(&:index) # getting all members from select list
  self.sltEndDate_element.options[lstMembers.sample].click
end
```

Comment: Nope, still the same warning. Problem is in this string: `lstMembers = self.sltMembers_element.options.map(&:index)` Because `map` method does not exist in page-object.

Comment: it must not be a collection :p  How can you get a collection of page elements using this gem?  If you can't, then selecting a random element will be tougher

Comment: Ok. Is some other way to select random option? May be via watir?

Comment: the issue is getting a collection - what does `self.sltMembers_element` return?